# Please help me!! Brownie doesn't compile but says it did

Tags: solidity

if i run brownie compile i get INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). Brownie v1.19.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\demos\brownie_simple_storage\build\contracts

But its not in there....

How can i solve this.
T.T please help me.....